# I need to make file server what H.W. should I use?

Tags: specifications

I need to make file server in Windows server 2008 and the clients will be 30 users connect at the same time to this server, they will write directly to this server, they will work on office and Autocad But the Autocad will only locate the file on file server and the process will be at the client so    Can I use this desktop
 **HP Elite 7100 MT Core i5** 
Features :
HP Elite 7100 MT
Intel Core i5-650 Processor (3.20 GHz/ 4 MB total cache)
Standard memory 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 SDRAM
Hard drive description 500 GB 7200 rpm SATA 3.0 Gb/s NCQ Smart IV
Graphics Integrated Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD
Optical drives SATA SuperMulti LightScribe DVD Writer
Network interface Integrated Realtek RTL8111DL Gigabit Ethernet
?

Comment: Can you, yes. Should you, no. An HP ML110 is cheap and better for a number of reasons. Call an HP (or Dell, IBM, etc - Or a 3rd Party like CDW and others) Sales rep and they'll have plenty of good reasons most relating to ROI.

Answer (score 3):

I would not . Seriously. You call a desktop with one 500gb disc a file server? Can I call that a carp little desktop, please.

Memory, discs are ok. The main problem I see is that you sould pretty much get out, get a NAS with 4-8  bays an d be happy with that. Something with RAID, multiple discs and able to SERVE FILES. 30 users hitting one disc is "slow" as in "the definition of a clueless admin causing 30 people to access files really slow and run around cursing him".